# Printing a string char by char in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, char, nasm

I am learning assembly and I want to know the basics very well so I can write more complete functions.

I want to print a string to the console char by char. The string is stored in a db type of variable. I have a function that I am calling print_string that compares the value stored  at the bx address to 0 because I have put a 0 at the end of my strings. After that I want to iterate through characters and print them one by one.

This is the code:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx, HELLO_MSG
call print_string

mov bx, GOODBYE_MSG
call print_string

jmp end

;%include "print_string.asm"

;DATA
HELLO_MSG:
        db "Hello, World!", 0
GOODBYE_MSG:
        db "Goodbye, World!", 0

;FUNCTIONS
print_string:
        cmp [bx], 0
        je the_end
        mov ah, 0x0e
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        add bx, 0x1
        jmp print_string

        the_end:
                ret

end:


jmp $

;padding and magic no
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I don't want to use any interrupts that may solve this problem.

This is my error message when I try to make a bin file:
[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of error messages; copy/paste the text into a code block so future readers with the same problem can search. And say which line that line number is.  Also, search on that error message yourself to find existing Q&As.

Comment: `cmp [bx], 0` doesn't know how big the data is you want to compare so it is throwing an error. `cmp byte [bx], 0` may do what you want as it would compare a single byte in memory at address [bx] with 0.